# NoSuchMethodError using maven

Tags: java, maven, gson

When I run my jar it throws an exception. I have decompiled the jar and found that the method exists. I have tried adding Gson and retrofit dependencies with the latest version in my own pom with no luck. What am I missing?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.Gson.newJsonReader(Ljava/io/Reader;)Lcom/google/gson/stream/JsonReader;
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:38) ~[?:?]
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27) ~[?:?]
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243) ~[?:?]
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:204) ~[?:?]
    at com.jaredsburrows.retrofit2.adapter.synchronous.SynchronousBodyCallAdapter.adapt(SynchronousBodyCallAdapter.java:27) ~[?:?]
```

I have read countless threads about the same/similar issues, but none of which helped solve this. This is my current pom:

```
...

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.theminecoder</groupId>
        <artifactId>agones-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>false</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Maven dependency:tree output:

```
[INFO] com.mycompany:artifact:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.spigotmc:spigot:jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] \- com.github.theminecoder:agones-java-sdk:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.14.9:compile
[INFO]    |     \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.17.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.jaredsburrows.retrofit:retrofit2-synchronousadapter:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO]    \- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO]       \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @maio290 I have tried adding gson on my pom but I don't see how that would make a difference as I found the gson classes in the jar either way.

Comment: your classpath is polluted. run `mvn dependency:tree` to found out conflicting versions (look for gson).

Comment: @rkosegi I added the output from `mvn dependency:tree` to the question. Seems to be working fine?

Comment: @Ferskfisk `converter-gson:jar:2.8.2:compile` and `gson:jar:2.8.5:compile` I bet these 2 versions must match ;)

Comment: Does the error still happen if you remove the shade plugin from the POM?

Comment: @maio290 Yes, that seems to have fixed this issue, however another exception (hopefully unrelated) popped up, opening a new thread if needed. Thanks!